# Is it a good idea to use html5 data attributes for javascript selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make it really obvious in the DOM that javascript code depends on the structure.  Is the following a good idea?

```
HTML:
<a class='submenu' data-submenu="true" .... </a>

JS:
var mySubnav = $("[data-submenu]");
```

Makes it really clear that javascript is operating on the html.  But I haven't seen this used by other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't just use classes for this case? If your links have a subnav class that's far more compatible and easy to parse, plus stylable, than a data-submenu attribute.

Comment: Seems like classes should be reserved for styling.  I'm afraid that someone might change the css classes, or see an unused class that's not in the stylesheets and remove it.  Using a data attribute seems more explicit that there's javascript that depends on the html structure.

Comment: There is nothing inherently style dependent on classes. The HTML specs defines classes as "As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style information to a set of elements).
For general purpose processing by user agents." This seems to fall into the latter.

Comment: +1, since jQuery even has extra functions for managing and selecting classes.